# Mpandroidchart How to set legend on left axis

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I need to put a legend in MPAndroidChart like the image this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84Wox8FntslUVhiM1R1OTJqbEE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

`chart.getLegend().setPosition(LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART);`

Comment: It's actually not the description about the line, but a description on the x-axis and y-axis showing what is each axis. Sorry if this comment was difficult to understand, I do not speak English.